# Numpy array as txt file with specific syntax

Tags: python, numpy, export

Right now I am using the following to save a txt file

```
np.savetxt(data.txt, data)
```

When I open the txt file the output looks something like the following:

```
1.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 1.169886320011951995e+02
2.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 1.622808196685386122e+02
3.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 1.167895805540496781e+02
```

But I need the output to look the following to be able to use it in another program. I.e the first two columns are just saved as integers and the last column should have no more than 8 decimal points.

```
1 0 1.16988632e+02
2 0 1.62280819e+02
3 0 1.16789580e+02
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `fmt` parameter. Try this:

```
np.savetxt('data.txt', data, fmt=['%d', '%d', '%1.8e'])
```